# How to find internal nodes in binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I already got the method to find external nodes but I have no idea about to count internal nodes so someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the following pseudocode to any language as per your preference.

```
function count_internal_nodes(curr):
       if curr == null: return 0
       else if curr is leaf: return 0
       else: return 1 + count_internal_node(curr.left) + 
                        count_internal_nodes(curr.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this algo

```
getInteriorNodes(self)
    count = 0
    hasLeft, hasRight = self.left<>null, self.right <>null
    if (hasLeft)
        count += self.left.getInteriorNodes()
    else if (hasRight)
        count += self.right.getInteriorNodes()
    else if ((hasLeft || hasRight) && self.parent) 
        count += 1
 return count
```